# Export Apple App Store analytics

Tags: ios, api, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to find a way, for gathering my App analytics (from analytics.itunes.apple.com) using API.

There is one same issue https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/98092#98092 ,from december 2015. Maybe something changed for today?

I found and try Official Reporter tool from Apple https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/ , but it's not exactly what i searching for.

Does Apple have API endpoint to download mobile app analytics?

I'm interested in one concrete metric: Count of my App installs by day or by selected time range.

I would be appreciate for any help! Thank you.

Comment: They have an app...

Comment: Can you give me more information? Thank you.

Comment: @Starlord the app doesn't offer usage data, nor is it a programatic interface, which is what the OP is after.

Answer (score -4):

There's no official API from Apple for that usage data, but our (Appfigures) API provides access to all of those metrics as well as other data iTunes Connect has like downloads, revenue, reviews, etc.

The API offers a few routes so you can get all of your essential analytics, but the main one you're after (installs) can be gathered using this request:

`https://api.appfigures.com/v2/reports/sales`

With no other modifiers that will give you the total installs for your app, as well as refunds, updates, and other related numbers.

```
{
    "downloads": 155299,
    "re_downloads": 133092
    "updates": 91156,
    "returns": 56,
    "net_downloads": 155243,
    "promos": 2,
    "revenue": "26188.63",
    "gross_revenue": "37412.32",
    "returns_amount": "609.21",
    "edu_downloads": 54,
    "gifts": 36,
    "gift_redemptions": 0,
    "edu_revenue": "0.00"
    "gross_returns_amount": "0.00",
    "gross_edu_revenue": "0.00",
    "uninstalls": 1811,
}
```

You can add a `group_by` and a date range to get more detailed. Using this request you'll be able to get downloads for your apps broken down by date, country, and for each app individually:

`https://api.appfigures.com/v2/reports/sales?group_by=product,date&start=-30`

Check out the complete documentation at https://docs.appfigures.com

*FYI - The API offers access to Android data as well.*